# Can't Authenticate Power Query to ASP.NET Core MVC Web App

Tags: authentication, odata, microsoft-identity-platform

Bottom line up front... when I try to connect Power Query from Excel to my app, I get the error described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectorauthentication#symptoms-when-the-service-isnt-configured-properly) - *We were unable to connect because this credential type isn’t supported for this resource. Please choose another credential type.*

Details...

1. My app was created from the ASP.NET Core Web App MVC template.
2. It uses the Microsoft Identity Platform for authentication.

```cs
// Sign-in users with the Microsoft identity platform
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
    {
        builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
        options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents();
        options.Events.OnTokenValidated = async context =>
        {
            //Calls method to process groups overage claim.
            var overageGroupClaims = await GraphHelper.GetSignedInUsersGroups(context);
        };
    })
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(options => builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options), initialScopes)
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

3. It uses Azure AD group claims for authorization.

```cs
// Adding authorization policies that enforce authorization using group values.
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Administrators", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new GroupPolicyRequirement(builder.Configuration["Groups:Administrators"])));
    options.AddPolicy("SuperUsers", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new GroupPolicyRequirement(builder.Configuration["Groups:SuperUsers"])));
    options.AddPolicy("Deliverables", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new GroupPolicyRequirement(builder.Configuration["Groups:Deliverables"])));
    options.AddPolicy("Orders", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new GroupPolicyRequirement(builder.Configuration["Groups:Orders"])));
    options.AddPolicy("Users", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new GroupPolicyRequirement(builder.Configuration["Groups:Users"])));
});
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, GroupPolicyHandler>();
```

4. In addition to the standard MVC UI, it also has an OData controller for API access.

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
//[Authorize(Policy = "Users")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public class OdataController : Controller Base
```

From a browser, everything works perfectly. Access is properly controlled by `[Authorize(Policy = "Users")]`.

From Excel, however, it only works if I set the controller to `[AllowAnonymous]` and use the Get Data > From Web option.

If I try Get Data > From OData Feed, I get an error *The given URL neither points to an OData service or a feed*. Which is OK as long as Get Data > From Web works.

If I add the authorization policy, I get an error *We were unable to connect because this credential type isn’t supported for this resource. Please choose another credential type*.

Following the supported workflow [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectorauthentication#supported-workflow), Power Query is expecting a 401 response with a WWW_Authentication header containing the Azure AD login URL. Instead, it's being sent directly to the Azure login, and therefore the authentication fails. I did try adding the Power Query client IDs to my Azure AD app, but that had no effect.

I have done every search I can think of and am out of ideas. Can anyone help? Thanks!